# Difference between github.token vs secrets.github_token?

Tags: github-actions

When configuring workflows for GitHub Actions there exists the option to pass a GitHub token to authenticate towards GitHub in the workflow.

I have seen both of the following ways to get said token:

```
github.token
secrets.github_token
```

Is there any functional difference between the two? Or are these simply two ways to get the same token?

Comment: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/authentication-in-a-workflow, https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/context-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions#github-context

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**Both are equivalent.**

- `github.token` is the syntax from the Github context, which contains information about the workflow run and the event that triggered the run ([source](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/context-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions#github-context)).
- `secrets.github_token` is the syntax referring to the GITHUB_TOKEN secret that GitHub automatically creates to use in your workflow. You can use the GITHUB_TOKEN to authenticate in a workflow run ([source](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/authentication-in-a-workflow#about-the-github_token-secret)).

*Note that these tokens have [specific permissions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/authentication-in-a-workflow#permissions-for-the-github_token), and that depending on what you want to do, you may need to create a [Personal Access Token](https://github.com/settings/tokens) (PAT) and add it as a secret (ex: ACCESS_TOKEN) to use in your workflow.*

Comment: A quick note: the `github` context and the `secrets` context aren't always available at the same time, so one might need to use one over the other.

Answer (score 7):

Apparently they are the same:

> `github.token`    `string`    A token to authenticate on behalf of the GitHub App installed on your repository. This is **functionally equivalent** to the GITHUB_TOKEN secret. For more information, see "Automatic token authentication."

Source: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#github-context